# Array.sort vs Array.take(x).sort Performance

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance, postgresql

I have an array of 3000 numbers.

Users grab a number, and then put it back at an arbitrary time within the following 5 seconds.

I want users to take the smallest number in the array every time.

At peak there would be a maximum of 100 people grabbing and replacing numbers at the same time. Would it be less expensive to select the first 100 and sort them, as opposed to sorting the entire array?

I am storing my array using Rails `serialize` in PostgreSQL with YAML

Comment: As with all performance related questions: **benchmark it.**

Comment: That's an odd question, because the results are not comparable.  In any event, taking the first 101 elements takes far less time than sorting the same number of elements, and sorting 101 elements takes a fraction of the time it takes to sort 30 times as many, so benchmarking is a waste of time.

Comment: @muistooshort That already answers 50% of my question.

Comment: @shiva what are you trying to do? If you have `[7, 3, 5, 10, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 4]`, sorting the first 3 items gives `[3, 5, 7]`, not `[1, 2, 3]`. The results are totally different.

Comment: I have a queue where users grab numbers and put them back. I want the smallest number to be given back every time @Stefan

Comment: @shiva maybe you should edit your question and describe your problem and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @shiva regarding your edit and my previous comment: `3` is not the smallest number in my example array, is it?

Comment: @Stefan edited again since you have trouble understanding

Comment: @shiva *"there would be a maximum of 100 people"* - so why don't you reduce the array to 100 numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complexity of most sorting algorithms are strict monotone increasing with respect to the length of the array (n, n log n, n^2, n n!, etc.) on average. Particularly, Ruby seems to use quicksort, which is n log n. Therefore, it is more expensive to sort an array of 3000 items than to sort an array of 100 items.

Comment: Besides that you are absolutely right, I wonder what would be a sense of sorting some part of an unsorted array?

Comment: @sawa : Perfect answer.. 1+

Comment: @sawa Thank you for your answer, but it answers half of the question. The full question is between the two processes of selecting the range within the array and then sorting the array, and simply sorting the whole array. Does the selecting take any time?

Comment: @shiva For that, you have to actually test it, but I suppose selecting a range is negligible.

Comment: How does an answer to a question that has 3 downvotes, have 4 upvotes, without being cheeky in any way shape or form. I tip my hat

Answer (score 0):

> I want users to take the smallest number in the array every time (...) would it be less expensive to select a range of numbers, and just sort that portion?

It would return the smallest number *within that range*, but not the smallest number within the array:

```
arr = [7, 3, 5, 10, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 4]

arr.take(3).sort #=> [3, 5, 7]
# vs
arr.sort.take(3) #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

> I am storing my array using Rails `serialize` in PostgreSQL with YAML

Sorting a Ruby array with 3,000 numbers takes less than a millisecond. Deserializing the YAML string is *much* slower.

Comment: I am glad we both understand the difference between a range and an array. The text you took out in the first quote is what defines the question.

Comment: But thank you for clearing out that deserializing the YAML is more expensive than Ruby sorting: I am trying to find the most efficient way to persist and read/write this array. Any ideas welcome

Comment: @shiva *"I am trying to find the most efficient way to persist and read/write this array"* - you should probably post a new question.